# How to transform multiple php arrays into one multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, pivot

I'm trying to transform many arrays with mostly similar data into a single array that has arrays in the keys for when there are more than one value. I think this is done as a pivot table in sql, but I would like to do this in PHP for other reasons.

I would like to transform:

```
$og=array();
$og[] = array('a'=>'cat', 'b'=>'beer', 'c'=>'wood');
$og[] = array('a'=>'cat', 'b'=>'beer', 'c'=>'bamboo');
$og[] = array('a'=>'cat', 'b'=>'beer', 'c'=>'concrete');
```

Into:

```
$new_array(
  'a'=>'cat',
  'b'=>'beer',
  'c'=>array('wood','bamboo','concrete')
);
```

I feel like this should be simple but for some reason I can't figure it out!

Comment: Would be even easier if you were ok with having arrays in all use cases, even if only one result. i.e. `'a' => array('cat')`

Comment: Well, have you tried anything at all? You'll need to show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to accomplish this:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach( $og as $data ) {
    foreach( $data as $k => $v ) {

        if( ! isset( $new_array[$k] ) )
            $new_array[$k] = array();

        $new_array[$k][] = $v;

    }
}

foreach( $new_array as $k => $data ) {
    $new_array[$k] = array_unique($data);

    if( count($new_array[$k]) == 1 )
        $new_array[$k] = $new_array[$k][0];

}
```

Check out [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). There may be a faster way to accomplish this, but this works.

Comment: If you were ok with having all results being an array, even if there is one result, then you could ditch the second `foreach` block

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I was trying to specify which key would be an array, but with this I don't have to. This will be very useful in a function for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the $og array and create your new array, like so:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($og as $parr=>$carr) {
    foreach($carr as $key=>$value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key,$new_array)) {
            $new_array[$key] = $value;
        }else if(!in_array($value,$new_array)) {
            if(is_array($new_array[$key])) {
                array_push($new_array[$key],$value);
            } else {
                $currentVal = $new_array[$key];
                $new_array[$key] = array($key=>$currentVal);
                array_push($new_array[$key],$value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a PHP Fiddle demo](https://3v4l.org/JbOtd).